# Xcode 6.1 (6A1046a) - invalid bundle

Tags: xcode, ios8, bundle

Today, I have installed the latest version of Yosemite (GM), and Xcode 6.1 (6A1046a).
Here is the message I get when I try to validate my iOS 8 app before submitting.

```
"iTunes Store operation failed.
This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to 
the app store must be built  with public (GM) version of 
Xcode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps built 
with beta software."
```

Note that I was able to submit my Swift app - on the Store since day #1 of iOS 8. As I have both GM (for Yosemite and Xcode), any idea why I have such a message?

Comment: You can not submit app with beta's of Xcode. Wyou will have to use Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: Xcode 6.1 (6A1046a) is a golden master seed 2, not a beta.

Comment: Well seed2 means it not yet released and thus you are not allowed to submit app build with it.

Comment: It's a GM seed 2. And I've posted already my app with this computer with Yosemite and Xcode (but previous versions...).